# What does "5B3/P" in CFM56-5B3/P mean?

Tags: jet-engine, terminology

For the CFM56 engine model CFM56-5B3/P, what does "5B3/P" mean?

Answer (score 1):

It's a more specific designation of the general engine. [There are lots of variants of the CFM56 in your case the 5B3/P variant:](https://www.asiaero.net/cfm56-5b-engine-models/)

> CFM56-5B3/P: Same as CFM56-5B1, except for increased thrust rating and
>   redesigned high pressure compressor, high pressure turbine, and low
>   pressure turbine.

[The type certificate has the specific info for it as well](https://www.easa.europa.eu/sites/default/files/dfu/TCDS%20E.003%20issue%2005.pdf). There is also lost of info on wikipedia under the [-5B series section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CFM_International_CFM56#CFM56-5B_series).